Upload LOB msi files to intune via graph API to programatically setup intune apps
I am trying to upload a windows LOB .msi App to MS Intune via the Graph API. This is part of a bigger script. So far I was able to figure out on how to get the Graph Token and create the App in the Intune portal. Problem is that I just cant figure out on how and where to upload my .msi file. I am fairly new to this and I wasnt really able to find anything usefull online that would help me with this problem.
I am guessing that with my current script im just trying to upload to the wrong endpoint / I cant even get the correct place. Online I've found multiple different suggestions, but none of them seem to be reasonable in my case. As said, im trying to upload an .msi file.
I cant quite figure out on how to get the contentVersionId or the fileId tho. Help would be very much appreciated here, I've been stuck on this for a while now. This is the code I already have to create the app, works like a charm;
`
$appInfo = isApp
# Azure AD Authentication Details
$tenantId = (Get-AzTenant).TenantId

Write-Host $appInfo.ClientSecret

# Generate OAuth Token
$authBody = @{
    grant_type    = "client_credentials"
    resource      = "https://graph.microsoft.com"
    client_id     = $appInfo.ApplicationId
    client_secret = $appInfo.ClientSecret
}

Write-Host "Graph-Token wird abgerufen, bitte warten..."

$authResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/token" -Method POST -Body $authBody
$graphToken = $authResponse.access_token

# Verify Token Retrieval
if (-not $graphToken) {
    Write-Error "Failed to retrieve access token."
    return
}
else {
    Write-Host "Access token retrieved successfully."
}


# Headers for Graph API requests (use the generated token)
$headers = @{
    "Authorization" = "Bearer $graphToken"
    "Content-Type"  = "application/json"
}


# App creation payload
$appPayload = @{
    "@odata.type"                   = "#microsoft.graph.windowsMobileMSI"
    displayName                     = "My LOB MSI App"
    productVersion                  = "1"
    description                     = "App Created via PS"
    publisher                       = "Protecdata"
    fileName                        = "TeamViewer.msi"
    isFeatured                      = $false
    minimumSupportedOperatingSystem = @{
        v10_0 = $true
    }
    appAvailability                 = "availableWithEnrollment"

} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10 -Compress


# Create the app
$appCreationUri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceAppManagement/mobileApps"
$appResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $appCreationUri -Method POST -Headers $headers -Body $appPayload

# Validate app creation
if (-not $appResponse) {
    Write-Error "App creation failed."
    return
}

# Extract Upload URI and App ID
$appId = $appResponse.id

`
What I've tried is this:
`
# Define Variables
$tenantId = (Get-AzTenant).TenantId
$filePath = "Z:\Serverwartungen\TeamViewer_Full.msi" # Path to the MSI file
# Ensure the file exists
if (-not (Test-Path $filePath)) {
    Write-Error "The file $filePath does not exist."
    return
}


# Retrieve App Information and Upload URL
Write-Host "Retrieving app information..."
$appInfoUri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceAppManagement/mobileApps/$appId"
$appInfoResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $appInfoUri -Method GET -Headers $headers

# Check if the response contains valid data
if (-not $appInfoResponse.contentVersions) {
    Write-Error "No content versions found in the app response."
    Write-Host $appInfoResponse
    return
}

if (-not $appInfoResponse.contentVersions[0].files) {
    Write-Error "No files found in the content version."
    return
}

# Get the upload URL
$uploadUrl = $appInfoResponse.contentVersions[0].files[0].uploadUrl
if (-not $uploadUrl) {
    Write-Error "Failed to retrieve the upload URL."
    return
}

# Upload the MSI File
Write-Host "Uploading MSI file..."
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uploadUrl -Method PUT -Headers @{"Content-Type" = "application/octet-stream" } -InFile $filePath

# Commit the Uploaded File
$fileId = $appInfoResponse.contentVersions[0].files[0].id
$commitUri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceAppManagement/mobileApps/$appId/contentVersions/1/files/$fileId/commit"

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $commitUri -Method POST -Headers $headers -Body @{}

# Publish the App
Write-Host "Publishing the app..."
$publishUri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceAppManagement/mobileApps/$appId"
$publishBody = @{
    "publishingState" = "published"
}

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $publishUri -Method PATCH -Headers $headers -Body ($publishBody | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10 -Compress)

Write-Host "MSI file uploaded and app published successfully."`

Sadly, the committedContentVersion is empty, thus I cant create the Link. Should this be automatically generated? When I try to manually set it in the app payload when creating the app, it doesnt work either. Any clues or help is appreciated!
